# Is it possible to set visual studio project properties in qmake .pro files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qmake

I have a qmake batch file which uses a .pri and .pro to create a visual studio C++ project which is used to create a dll.  But I would like to setup the properties of this project automatically, particularly the debugging command and command line arguments is this possible in qmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, create a

> add_qt_path.pri

file somewhere with the following contents:

```
# test if windows
win32 {
  # test if already exists
  VCXPROJ_USER_FILE = "$${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}.vcxproj.user"
  !exists( $${VCXPROJ_USER_FILE}) {
    # generate file contents
    TEMPNAME     = $${QMAKE_QMAKE}     # contains full dir of qmake used
    QTDIR        = $$dirname(TEMPNAME) # gets only the path
    # vcxproj.user template
    VCXPROJ_USER = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
    <Project xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'\">$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$${QTDIR};%PATH%</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      </PropertyGroup>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'\">$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$${QTDIR};%PATH%</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      </PropertyGroup>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'\">$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$${QTDIR};%PATH%</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      </PropertyGroup>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      <PropertyGroup Condition=\"'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'\">$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=$${QTDIR};%PATH%</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
      </PropertyGroup>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
    </Project>$$escape_expand(\\n)\
    "
    # write file
    write_file($${VCXPROJ_USER_FILE}, VCXPROJ_USER)  
  }
}
```

then **include** it into your qmake project (*.pro) file, **after** the TARGET deifnition:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = test3
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

include(./../../add_qt_path.pri) # add qt path to vs project

# other qmake stuff
```

You can also add to the *.vcxproj.user any other entries such as debugging command and command line arguments, just take a look on how Visual Studio auto generates the in the *.vcxproj.user file when you set them up manually.

Comment: This worked great for me thank you! I had to fix a typo.

`http://$$escape_expand">schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`

Should be just:
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`

Answer (score 2):

Most of the build environment properties can be setup through qmake options (you can find them in qmake sources e.g. *_objectmodel.* files ). Unfortunately, both options you need are in fact runtime options so I don't think you'll be able to set them in the .pri/.pro files. Afaik, they're not even stored in the .vcxproj file but in the .vcxproj.user file. If it was not for this then modifying qmake could have been an option, even though it wouldn't probably worth the effort.